# why jquery scroll to not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with this jquery code

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="#feature2" id="a-down">Click</a>
        <script src="/project/patch/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#a-down').click(function(){
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop : $("#feature2").offset().top
                }, 2000);
            });
        })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When i click a url like this `http://localhost:8080/project/app/client/index.html#!#feature4` it is not working, but when i do it with different url, it is working fine and these urls  don't have `#!#`

Please help me. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to explain more clearly what is supposed to happen, and what actually happens (including mentioning any error messages that show in the console).

Comment: yes it jumps to directly and animate scroll not work

Comment: @nnnnnn no error in console , this question have been edit . Can you help me ?

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't work if the URL is referencing a different page? You can't navigate to a different page and then animate that page using JS from the previous page. If you're talking about just within a single page, you probably want to use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the default click behaviour that would be to jump straight to the element in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to scroll to top of the `div` 'feature2', you can use following :

```
<html>
<body>
    <a href="#feature2" id="a-down">Click</a>
    <script src="/project/patch/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#a-down').click(function(){
            $('#feature2').animate({
                scrollTop : $("#feature2").offset().top
            }, 2000);
        });
    })
    </script>
</body>
```

You should animate only the `div` that you want to scroll.

Hope this helps!